# How to remove duplicates from a row which contains comma separated values?

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I have been converting some R code to HQL (Hive). I am stuck at something. 
I have a col "values" and this is basically concatenation of some other cols separated by comma.

`e.g values
    a,b,c,a,a
    a,a,c,c,c
    d,c,e,f,e
I want to something like this:
    Values
    a,b,c,,
    a,c,,,
    d,c,e,f,`

How do I do this in Hive? Help!
Note: This is one col. 
[image: Sample/Example]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need empty strings and extra commas in the final table, then you can split strings by comma, explode the resulting array and then collect set, e.g.

```
with table1 as (
  select row_number() over () as id, values
    from initial_table
),
table2 as (
  select id, value
    from table1
  lateral view explode(split(values, ',')) vals as value
),
table3 as (
  select id, collect_set(value) as values
    from table2
   group by id
)
select concat_ws(values, ',') as values
  from table3
```